# How do I multiply a list of elements with another list of lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two list with arbitrary numbers: `list_1 = [2,4]` and `list_2 = [[10,20,30], [100,1000,10000]]` i need the first index of `list_1`(i.e `list_1[0]`) to multiply with each number in `list_2[0]`(i.e the sub_list). the same should happen with the next index such as in a for loop.
so far i have tried

```
list_1 = [2,4]
list_2 = [[10,20,30], [100,1000,10000]]
for i in list_1:
    for j in list_2:
        print(i * j)
```

The code either duplicates the list or throws an error at me. any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `list_2` is a `list` of `list`s. Do you want to multiply the values in the sub-`list`s (flattening `list_2` such that the internal `list` structure is ignored)? Duplicating the `list` is the correct behavior otherwise `2 * [10, 20, 30]` is sequence multiplication, and is supposed to produce `[10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30]`.

Comment: I need to have list_1[0] or 2, multiply with each number in the first sub-list of list_2 resulting in 20, 40, 60.  then list_1[1] or 4 multiply with list_2(sub_list 2) and give 400, 4000, 40000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading you correctly, for your example, you want `list_1[0]` to be multiplied by each element of `list_2[0]`, and `list_1[1]` to be multiplied by each element of `list_2[1]`. The correct way to do this is to `zip` `list_1` and `list_2` together (to get the multiplier and the associated sub`list` as pairs), then have an inner loop over the sub`list`:

```
for op1, sublist in zip(list_1, list_2):
    for op2 in sublist:
        print(op1 * op2)
```

Your code failed, because you were (effectively) trying to multiply `op1` by *each* `sublist`, not the *contents* of *one* `sublist`, so you invoked sequence multiplication, performing `2 * [10, 20, 30]` to get `[10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30]`, and `2 * [100, 1000, 10000]` to get `[100, 1000, 10000, 100, 1000, 10000]`, rather than multiplying `2` by `10`, `20` and `30` individually as intended.

Answer (score -2):

```
    list_1 = [2,4]
    list_2 = [[10,20,30], [100,1000,10000]] 
    for i in range(len(list_1)):
...     for item in list_2:
...             for j in range(len(item)):
...                     print(list_1[i]*item[j])
```

Returns

```
20
40
60
200
2000
20000
40
80
120
400
4000
40000
```